# Vue 3 axios sending formdata

Tags: javascript, vue.js, express, vuejs3

I am trying to upload photos to a backend expressjs API. In my Vue 3 setup, I am creating a formdata object "files" and passing it to axios to post to the server. However, the server does not get anything (req.files is undefined). Server code is tested working via Postman, but it doesn't work with my Vue code. Here are the vue code snippets:

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">

    <FileSelector v-model="files" :accept="['image/*']">

      <DialogButton>Add</DialogButton>

      <PhotoPreview v-for="file in files" :key="file" :image="file"></PhotoPreview>
    </FileSelector>

    <button type="submit">upload</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

```
setup() {
    const files = ref([])
    const axios = inject('axios')
    const { loading, data, error, axiosPostFormData} = useApi('/photo')

    const onSubmit = async () => {
      try {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("files", files.value)
        console.log(files.value)
        await axiosPostFormData(formData)
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    }

    return {
      files, onSubmit
    }
  }
}
```

Files object shows as this proxy object. Is this correct?

```
Proxy {0: File}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(1)
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

If I change to this, it works.

```
formData.append("files",  files.value[0])
```

How do I send multiple files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead `formData.append("files", files.value)` for one file, for many try like this:

```
for (const file of files.value) {
  formData.append('files', file) 
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. Thanks